# Avoid leaving page confirmation when user clicks on hyperlinks

Tags: javascript

This method brings the confirmation message when user leaves the current page:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
              var confirmationMessage = "¿Seguro?";

              e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
              return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
        });
```

This includes also clicking on links which is normal as that's also leaving a page.

As I have already seen on other websites, what's the Javascript way to avoid this message to appear on hyperlink clicking?

Comment: you could whitelist the ones that shouldn't trigger the message since it seems you want to create a confirmation only when someone leaves YOUR app

Answer (score 0):

If `e.returnValue` is anything but an empty string, the confirmation will appear. You should check to see what object initiated the event and set that value accordingly:

```
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
          var confirmationMessage = "";

          // Only set the message when the target wasn't a link
          if(e.target.nodeName !== "A"){
              confirmationMessage = "¿Seguro?";
          }

          e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
    });
```